# Clear EditText data inside beforeTextChanged() of TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have to watch `EditText` in my App in such a way that if in `EditText` data is in 2 lines 
then again I want to write in 3rd line then previous 2 line's data should get clear.

For this I am using following way to do

```
mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        private int lines;

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            Log.v("", "inside ontextchnaged");

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

            lines = getTotalLines(txtDataSource);
            if (lines == 2) {                   

                   txtDataSource.removeTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
                Log.v("", txtDataSource.getText().toString());
                txtDataSource.setText("");
                txtDataSource.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.v("", "inside aftertextchanged");

        }
    };

    txtDataSource.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
```

and I am getting no of lines enter by the below code

```
private int getTotalLines(EditText editText) {
    int lineNumber = 0;
    String text = editText.getText().toString()
            .substring(0, editText.getSelectionStart());

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (String.valueOf(text.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("\n")) {
            lineNumber++;
        }
    }

    return lineNumber;
}
```

So when i m getting 2 lines data in `EditText` then I am removing watcher from `EditText` 
then clearing data of `EditText` and again I added watcher on `EditText` .

Every thing working fine but problem is after 2 lines when I start to wrote then it is not writing first character which I enter from Keypad it starts writing from second character input.

So after 2 lines when enter 2 characters then it didnt write first char which i enter it starts writing from second character.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks ....

Comment: Where is your getTotalLines(txtDataSource); method?

Comment: I updated in my question

Comment: I think you getLines method included your new character

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < text.length()-1; i++) {
        if (String.valueOf(text.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("\n")) {
            lineNumber++;
        }
try with above loop.
    }

Comment: @pratik  let me try this too

Comment: @patik nope it deos not help

Comment: i alreday posted my edittext code...

Comment: but how can I debug without your proper code.

Comment: nope not possible to post poject

Comment: Your wish dear...,if would find anything in this then let me know you.

Comment: I think you should put your code on onTextChanged method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue.

It may not be standard way to do, but I didn't find any other way to do this inside 
**beforeTextChanged()**

I solved using the below code inside **onTextChanged()**

```
     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

 lines = getTotalLines(txtDataSource);

  if (lines == 2 ) {

     String frstChar = String.valueOf(s.toString().charAt(s.toString().length() - 1));
     txtDataSource.removeTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);

 txtDataSource.setText("" + frstChar);

     txtDataSource.setSelection(txtDataSource.getText().toString().length());

 txtDataSource.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);

}
   }
```

and now in 3rd line first character is getting displayed in EditText.

I am sharing my way so that if someone else would face such issue they can solve by this way..

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try to solve the problem when you edit from the middle of the word.

"setSelection" keeps forcing you to write at the end of the text.